# multiply two varchars in sql

Tags: sql, mariadb, varchar

This what I have tried but it is giving errors:

```
MariaDB [test]> create table table1 (length varchar, breadth varchar);                                                             
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' breadth varchar)' at line 1
MariaDB [test]> create table table1 (length varchar(20), breadth varchar(20));                                                         
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
MariaDB [test]> insert into table1 (length, breadth) values ('12','11');                                                                                                                               
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)                                                                                                                                                                    

MariaDB [test]> select * from table1;                                                                                                                                                                  
+--------+---------+                                                                                                                                                                                   
| length | breadth |                                                                                                                                                                                   
+--------+---------+                                                                                                                                                                                   
| 12     | 11      |                                                                                                                                                                                   
+--------+---------+                                                                                                                                                                                   
1 row in set (0.02 sec)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
MariaDB [test]> select convert (int, length)*convert(int, breadth) as T from table1;                                                                                                                   
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'int, length)*convert(int, breadth) as T fr
om table1' at line 1                                                                                                                                                                                   
MariaDB [test]> select convert(int, length)*convert(int, breadth) as T from table1;                                                                                                                    
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'int, length)*convert(int, breadth) as T fr
om table1' at line 1
```

Comment: Why are you using `varchar` to store numbers?  Seems like that would fix your problem.

Comment: Use integer data type for integer data...

Comment: Why are you trying to multiply `VARCHAR`...?  Why not just create them as `INT`...?

Comment: `Length()` is a function in MySQL. I suspect that you should stick some backticks around that field or consider changing the name to something that isn't a keyword.

Comment: If that doesn't solve the problem, are you seeing the same behavior using `CAST()` -  `CAST(lengthfield as int) * CAST(breadth as int)`

Comment: lolzzz...comments and upvotes. This is just an  example where in actual database has few numbers entered as char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cast()`:

```
select cast(length as int) * cast(breadth as int) as T
from table1;
```

As explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-convert.html), `convert()` is for converting between different character sets.  You are confusing MySQL's (and MariaDB's) use of `convert()` with SQL Server's.

By the way, you do not even need the explicit `cast()` (at least in MySQL).  The engine will do an implicit cast for you:

```
select length * breadth as T from table1;
```

Although this is supported, I don't really advocate depending on implicit casts.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bae4f/2) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @Hogan . . . MariaDB is *very* compatible with MySQL:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/.  Because the MariaDB project strives for compatibility with MySQL, I doubt they would re-purpose a built-in, documented MySQL function.

Comment: yes, I got switched around -- you are saying in ms sql convert can be used to change types but not in Maria?

Comment: @Hogan . . . The use of `convert()` in the OP is compatible with SQL Server. It is not compatible with MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: @paul . . . The link is now in the answer, but here is the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-convert.html.